# Newly created project on Eclipse with Android SDK does not recognize import statement

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a sample HelloWorld app on Android using Eclipse! It's not importing a java package. What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: How do you compile your code? What error do you get? What package do you have installed?

Comment: Could you expands the `libs` folder to see what is there? It seems that your project did not have android support library. If so, download and copy the android support from `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs`.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I only had v4 in the lib folder. I copied the v7 from my SDK folder to my app project. I'm getting another issue related to R

Comment: If you use v7, you can remove v4.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your project. This link explains: http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/12/How-to-force-Eclipse-to-rebuild-generated-resource-class-R-in-Android-project.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to remove error from res folder its might be a reason nd then clean your project

2.Check you add android support v7 appcompat library in your project if not then first you have to add it in your project and also clear android support v7 appcompat library. if library having error then never reslove in your project.

may this info. help to you :)